# union of left and right joins sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to wrap my head around union of left and right join but I just can not seem to do it as the tables have different values in them as such:

```
Table1  
table1ID, clientNo, clientName, ClientCity  
Table2  
table2ID, RoomNo, clientNo, DateTo, DateFrom
```

What I need to do is join the 2 to get the following values:
clientName, clientCity, roomNo, dateFrom, DateTo

I have tried multiple ways to do this and as there is only 2 fields in table1 I get errors all the time and it will not accept NULL as a select field.
Much appreciated :)

Thanks

Rob

Comment: Help us help you  - please share some sample data, the result you'd like to get for it, the query you've already tried and the error you're getting from it.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Nobody ever uses RIGHT JOIN - but I guess that's no reason not to. ;-)

Comment: I am using MySQL Tim, and true Strawberry, my boss wants it done so I have to do it lol, I will have to talk to the others and see what he has got them doing.

Comment: Switch to left join anyway. It's so much easier to understand `main table left join optional data`, instead of `optional data right join main table`.

Answer (score 3):

As I see there is a `clientNo` in both tables, so you must join on that field.

```
SELECT t1.clientMame,
       t1.clientCity,
       t2.roomNo,
       t2.dateFrom,
       t2.dateTo
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table t2
    ON t1.clientNo = t2.clientNo
```

INNER JOIN will bring you only rows that are in both tables, if you want to show clients without rooms use LEFT JOIN.

Here is a nice picture that illustrates joins in SQL:

[image: illustration of joins]

Comment: Thank you :) but I am suppose to to a UNION of a left and a right join.

Comment: I add about left join. Just change inner to left :)

Comment: And UNION is another operation: If you want to unite few recordsets in one, there are only two tables 1 join will be enough.

Comment: That works a treat but the boss said I was asked to do a UNION of a LEFT & RIGHT JOIN. The main thing here is he wants it as a UNION for some reason. This is only part of what he wants, other people are working on other parts too.

Comment: In that case, please, add some samples of data in tables and what result you want to archive. I add some info about joins to my answer.

Comment: All I have been given is what I posted in the start, table1 and table2, and what you have given me was correct except he wanted a left and right join union of the information

Comment: Well, as you can see from a picture that I posted Union of left and right is full outer join, it will bring ALL rows from both tables, if there are no corresponded data ut will show NULLs.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
select clientNo,clientName,clientCity, RoomNo as "",DateTo as "", DateFrom as "" from Table1
union 
select clientNo,clientName as "",clientCity as "",RoomNo,DateTo,DateFrom from Table2
```

If you want to do a union you must have same count of column otherwise you have to declare and make the field value as empty or null,
You should have same order of the column set in your select query of the both table